# I added new input fields to my PHP form but it no longer posts data to SQL server

Tags: php, html, forms

I followed a guide to make a simple registration form which worked but I wanted to add more input fields. But I now no longer posts the data to the SQL database.

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $email = $postcode = $area = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $email_err = $postcode_err = $area_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else {
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else {
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else {
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later. (username)";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Validate password
    if (empty(trim($_POST["password"]))) {
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif (strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6) {
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else {
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if (empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))) {
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else {
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if (empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)) {
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if (empty($username_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($postcode_err) && empty($area_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)) {

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, postcode, area, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_email, $param_postcode, $param_area, $param_password);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_postcode = $postcode;
            $param_area = $area;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else {
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later. last";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

And the html form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err; ?></span>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($postcode_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <label>Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $postcode_err; ?></span>
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($area_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <label>Area</label>
        <input type="text" name="area" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $area; ?>">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $area_err; ?></span>
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
    </div>

    <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
</form>
```

Comment: I would inspect this line: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_email, $param_postcode, $param_area, $param_password);`

Answer (score 0):

See comments for reasons:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
            // Set parameters
            // Pointless to just create copies of variables here
            //$param_username = $username;
            //$param_email = $email;
            //$param_postcode = $postcode;
            //$param_area = $area;
            //$param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            // Second parameter here needs to match the number of ?s in your prepared query. I'm going to assume they're all strings
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $username, $email, $postcode, $area, password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else {
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later. last";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked, i did not see i needed to add three extra s's to make it work. However the $email, $postcode and $area are not saving in the database

Comment: You never set those variables to the data from the POST. You can substitute the following in this case: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $username, $_POST['email'], $_POST['postcode'], $_POST['area], password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));`